# IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, PHPStorm, etc. - cursor / caret stuck, jumps back to previous position, sticks to scroll

Tags: intellij-idea, selection, behavior, caret

i am really annoyed by weird caret / cursor behaviour inside IntelliJs editor.

The caret sometimes get stuck at some line at the beginning. If you try to navigate by arrow-keys or something else despite the mouse when this happens, the caret will instantly jump back to the previous position. Only way to set it free is to click with the mouse somewhere else in the editor window.

[image: intellij bug1]

In addition to it, if the caret is stuck and you scroll, the caret moves the same amount of lines you scroll in the editor and will select all text on its way.

[image: intellij bug2]

So the question is: what can i do about it?

env: macOS 10.12.4, recent JetBrains IDEs (tried several versions)

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the steps to reproduce and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: I have precisely the same problem. Support wasn't able to help. @progmem were you able to find a fix? Do you use a trackpad by any chance?

Comment: @TigranPetrossian the bug was caused by a window manager called Magnet. As soon as is uninstalled it, everything worked fine.

Comment: @progmem Oh man... I'm a magnet user too. Thank you so much, this has been bugging me from quite some time now. Mind posting an answer when you've got a second?